# PHP pdf generate issue for japanese character

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Hi I am using **tcpdf** library of PHP for creating PDF.
In this I am using cid0jp font for supporting Japanese character. But after putting option for download.

Ex:

```
$pdf = new PDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetMargins(15, 27, 15);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 25);
$pdf->SetFont('cid0jp', '', 14);
$pdf->SetMargins(30, 20);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Write($h=0, '木曜日', $link='', $fill=0, $align='C', $ln=true, $stretch=0, $firstline=false, $firstblock=false, $maxh=0);
$pdf->Output('example_002.pdf', 'D');
```

But after downloading the generated PDF does not have any content.
Can anyone knows what is the issue?

Comment: please check this in your code <=> UTF-8." $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); "...

Comment: @MKV Thanks for your reply, I have checked and my code is same as u said...

Comment: Do you have the Eastern language support installed for your PDF viewer? cid0jp references a font expected to be provided by the PDF viewer.  I can run the code you provided without issue.  Also, be sure your TCPDF library is up to date.

Comment: @EPB sorry for late reply...issue was becouse PDF viewer doues not have the font required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was because PDF viewer does not have the font required...Downloaded the required font...this fixed the issue. The sample code provided above is correct...

Comment: Could I ask where you got a font for Japanese kanji?

Answer (score -1):

"cid0jp" this font supports Japanese text.

```
 $xmlWriter->SetFont('cid0jp', '', 14);
```